React native menu button knockout transparency
I hired a designer to help me revamp an app I'm working on and I like the menu treatment, but am not sure how to accomplish what looks simple in RN.  Have tried a few solutions but no luck so far :(
I have seen some examples using SVG potentially, but then getting the button to sit inside the divot is also tripping me up.


Found a library doing exactly what I needed!
https://github.com/hoaphantn7604/react-native-curved-bottom-bar
